# flower of life geometry question

Tags: geometry

Attached is the question - with so many circles i haven't figured out a way to calculate what's asked. Would really appreciate some help. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68DZV.png)

Comment: A straightforward approach: find the areas of a single 'lens' and a single 'triangle', then count how many of each there are to get the total covered area.

Comment: (Originally posted as part of a comment on an answer that has now been deleted for some unknown reason.) You could use the facts (1) the points of contact of the large circle with the smaller circles form an inscribed regular hexagon, (2) a circle of radius $1$ has area $\pi,$ (3) an equilateral triangle of side $1$ has area $\sqrt3/4,$ (4) a part of one of the smaller circles has $1/9$ the area of a similar part of the large circle,.

Comment: also not sure why the other answer disappeared, still trying to figure out best way to solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

Area above horizontal line of radius length r is only the outer area left out near periphery marked yellow on one of six minor segments.

$$ A_{segment}=\pi r^2/6- r^2 \sqrt{3}/4= r^2(\pi/6-\sqrt {3}/4) $$
Area of  an equilateral triangle is known $ =(r^2 \sqrt{3}/4$ )

The smaller radius segments are a third in length and 1/9 in area. There are three such small areas/patches, so remaining area is  $A_s-3\cdot \dfrac19 A_s = \dfrac23 A_s$

There are six such areas in a regular hexagon totalling to

$$6 \cdot \frac23 A_s = 4 A_s = \frac23 r^2 (\pi-3 \sqrt {3}/2)$$
where we plugged in from above value for $A_{segment}.$

[image]

Fraction of total area = $\dfrac{4 A_s}{\pi r^2} = \dfrac23-\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\pi}= 11.5338 \,$%

Comment: one of the very best answers i ever seen here

Answer (score 3):

There are six regions around the exterior that are not part of any of the smaller circles.  You are asked what percentage of the large circle they represent.  The inner area is divided into lenses and triangles with curved sides, which we can call deltas.  You should compute the area of a lens and a delta, count how many of each there are, and add up the areas to get the total area of the small circles.

Comment: lens is 2(6pi-9sqrt(3)); delta is 36sqrt(3)-18pi